# how to send mail using swiftmailer - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I tried to send email using swiftmailer in Yii2. I'm still beginner for this framework. This is my basic code:

```
public function sendMail($email)
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $email = Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'];
            $mailto = 'user@gmail.com'; // need to change
            $isi = "blablabla";

            Yii::$app->mailer->compose("@app/mail/layouts/html", ["content" => $isi])
                ->setTo($mailto)
                ->setFrom($email)
                ->setSubject('coba')
                ->send();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In my case, I want to setup a 'setTo' based on my `usr` table. Field of my `usr` table:

```
id | username | manager | email           | type     |
1  | fauzi    | arie    | fauzi@gmail.com | user     |
2  | arie     | rian    | arie@gmail.com  | approver |
```

For example, when user with id = 1 login then he's create a new post and after click submit, the action also send email to user with id = 2 (manager of fauzi) for some review before post is publish to public. Thank you.

Comment: Have you configured the mailer component in your config main.php file properly?

Comment: Yes, I have configured it. If I tried my code, it's working properly. But, I need to get a 'setTo' from a field email in table of my db.

Answer (score 0):

note: I assume your `usr` table has model called `User` if not, then change it to fit your code

you can provide also array of email adresses
like

```
->setTo(['email1@email.com', 'email1@email.com' => 'Name Surname'])
```

What you want to know is which users you want to get, maybe add some conditions to activerecord etc...

```
$users = User::find()->all();
```

or

```
// or any condition you need in your application, this is just example
$users = User::find()->andWhere(['type' => 'approver'])->all();
```

then `Variant #1` you can loop trough all records

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // you can add here some conditions for different types of users etc
    // ... your code to send email ...
    ->setTo([$user->email => $user->username])
    // or just 
    // ->setTo($user->email)
}
```

or `Variant #2` you can get all emails first

```
$emails = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($users, 'email');
// ... your code to send email ...
->setTo($emails)
// ...
```